# Loop though network share and list all users folders and create/delete file

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

We have 1 main network share named the below, after the underscore there is 8 locations which are "abc$", "def$", "ghi$", "jkl$", "mno$", "pqr$", "stu$", "vwxyz$".

Depending on the users first letter in their username a folder is created with the which is the users home area.

Example username - AdamB will be put in `Networkshare1_abc$`.

Example 2 username - EdwardB will be put in `Networkshare1_def$`

Within this folder are the is a list of all users as a folder

```
Networkshare1_abc$  
Networkshare1_def$  
Networkshare1_ghi$  
Networkshare1_jkl$  
Networkshare1_mno$  
Networkshare1_pqr$  
Networkshare1_stu$  
Networkshare1_vwxy$
```

I need a script that will

1. that will loop though only the top folder list the users
2. check to see if a text file exists and if it does delete it (have this working below)

   ```
   $Wantedfile = "Networkshare1_stu$\user1\test.txt"
   $timeStamp = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm")
   $FileName = $timeStamp + ".txt"

   if ((Test-Path $Wantedfile$FileName) -eq $false) {
     Write-Host "file does not exists"
   } elseif ((Test-Path $Wantedfile$FileName) -eq $true) {
     Write-Host "file present..removing file"
     Remove-Item $Wantedfile$FileName
   }
   ```

The bit I am struggling with is the loop and how to get it to check each folder in the above locations as streamline as possible.

Comment: You can enumerate the top-level items of a share like this: `Get-ChildItem '\\server\share\*'`. Or the second-level items like this: `Get-ChildItem '\\server\share\*\*'`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thank you Ansgar that answers to somewhat. What I need it do to is too loop at the start and loop though each top level folder (networkshare1_abc$) and then just the script above, then it to move to networkshare1_def$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your files are really named like

> "Networkshare1_stu$\user1\test.txt03-21-2017-19-41.txt"

but basically what you need is `foreach` loop. You need to get all the folders in the top folder. In `$directories` you will have `abc$`, `def$` etc. folders. Then you will loop through each of them and search for the file using `Where-Object`.

```
$nameOfFile = "test.txt"
$fullPathFile = "\\Networkshare1_abc$\user1\test.txt"
$directories = Get-ChildItem "\\Networkshare1" -Directory

foreach($directory in $directories)
{
    Write-Host "Searching in $directory.FullName ..."
    $files = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like "*$nameOfFile"}
    # or to use fullPathFile
    # $files = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.FullName -eq $fullPathFile}

    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        Write-Host "Removing $file.FullName - continue?"
        Read-Host ""
        Remove-Item $file -Force
    }
}
```